# Can we filter shopify products by weight using storefront GQL API?

Tags: shopify, shopify-storefront-api

We are selling jewellery online and we need to implement product-filtering based on product weight using GQL.

I believe we need to do this in `query` param in `products` query.
Something like `query: {'minWeight':'10', unitOfWeight: 'GMS'}`, this should list all products whose weight is greater than 10gms.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The default query params for the StoreFront GraphQL API for the products are as follow:

```
available_for_sale
created_at
product_type
tag
title
updated_at
variants.price
vendor
```

There is no weight there, so **no** there is no way to achieve this with the StoreFront API.

The best approach will be to create a smart collection with the proper conditions to meet what you are looking for (since the collection allows for weight conditions) and make an ajax request to it to get the products.

Comment: User can select range of any values like `1gms` to `10gms` or `100gms` to `200gms`. I don't think smart collections is an answer because it expects we know what user inputs.

Comment: How about I use add weight as a tag and pass about 20 to 50 tags in query something like `tag:weight_100gms OR tag:weight_10gms OR tag:weight_25gms`. What do you think?

Comment: @UdayReddy yes you can use tags but will be a very tedious job to add and manage them.

Comment: Are you aware of any limitation with number of tags that can be in a query?

Comment: @UdayReddy I haven't reached a limit as of yet, but there might be. Can't confirm or deny this.